# count of matching rows in R

Tags: r

below is the sample table/Data frame. The third attribute (count) will give the count of similar rows(attribute1+attribute2)

```
╔════╦═════════════╦═════════════╦══════════════════════════════╗
║ ID ║ Attribute 1 ║ Attribute 2 ║ count(Attribute1+Attribute2) ║
╠════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬══════════════════════════════╣
║  1 ║ A           ║ AA          ║                            3 ║
║  2 ║ B           ║ CC          ║                            1 ║
║  3 ║ C           ║ BB          ║                            2 ║
║  4 ║ A           ║ AA          ║                            3 ║
║  5 ║ C           ║ BB          ║                            2 ║
║  6 ║ D           ║ AA          ║                            1 ║
║  7 ║ B           ║ AA          ║                            1 ║
║  8 ║ C           ║ DD          ║                            1 ║
║  9 ║ A           ║ AB          ║                            1 ║
║ 10 ║ A           ║ AA          ║                            3 ║
╚════╩═════════════╩═════════════╩══════════════════════════════╝
```

**Update :**

Thanks `akrun` and `danas.zuokas` for the help. 
the final output I am expecting would look something like this. where I am choosing 50% from each count group .ex : for ID 1,4,10 the count is 3. I would need to choose only 2 (50%) for each count group hence I should get (A,AA) twice .

```
 ID    Attribute 1  Attribute 2     count(Attribute1+Attribute2)
        1   A   AA  3
        2   B   CC  1
        3   C   BB  2
        4   A   AA  3
        6   D   AA  1
        7   B   AA  1
        8   C   DD  1
        9   A   AB  1
```

Comment: The condition is not clear

Comment: what are you counting in the 4th column

Comment: the 4th column is the count of `attribute1 and attribute 2` together

Comment: In the future use `dput` or some other more amenable means of sharing your data. "Pretty" ASCII tables cannot be easily be transferred into others' R sessions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given your data is in `df`:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt[, count := .N, by = list(Attribute1, Attribute2)]
```

Comment: Any reason you're `paste`ing the columns? I assume this will take longer than just grouping by both..?

Comment: You are right - just "translated" from SQL.

Comment: You are welcome Zahoor Kazi! You can also mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

We can try

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     group_by(attribute1, attribute2) %>%
     mutate(Count= n())
```

Comment: what is `%>%` ? I am unable to run teh code with that

Comment: @ZahoorKazi It is the pipe/chain which connect the lhs and rhs

Comment: how can Choose only few records (say 30%) for each count group?

Comment: @ZahoorKazi  You may use `df1 %>%  group_by(attribute1, attribute2) %>% slice(seq(round(0.3*n())))`

Comment: thanks akrun, but that seems to be giving some different result. what I am required to get is , the rows with ID 1,4,10 have appeared 3 times. now I need to select only 30% ( 1 row irrespetive of ID) of it. and same for other count groups

Comment: @ZahoorKazi Can you update your post with the expected output.  It's not clear to me.  Or better would be to post that as a separate question.